# What are the security procedures at Holyhead ferry port?

Tags: luggage, security, ferries

I’m travelling to Dublin via ferry in Easter, and I’m going on the ferry between Holyhead port and Dublin port. I’ve crossed in a car so I know how the security works with vehicles, but I’m going to be travelling as a foot passenger. What are the security checks like as a foot passenger? Are bags X-rayed or searched?

Thanks

Comment: What were you thinking of smuggling? The less suspicious version of this question would be "what items or substances are prohibited on the Dublin/Holyhead ferry"

Comment: @SJuan76 That's what "checkin X minutes before departure" rules are for.

Comment: @SJuan76 yh ur funny fam bored internet wasteman

Answer (score 2):

I travelled westbound with Stena Line and eastbound with Irish Ferries in 2017, between Holyhead and Dublin.  I was a foot passenger with a bicycle.  Westbound, I had to check in my bicycle.  I don't know if there was a scan after check in.  Eastbound, I rode my bicycle + luggage onto the ferry with the cars.  Either way, none of the luggage I carried on-board was scanned, but when I arrived as a foot passenger there were some officials who could have stopped people for a check, but didn't.

Incidentally, in neither direction did anybody ask me to identify myself at any moment.